# Why use Uploadify?

Tags: uploadify

Could somebody mention the advantages of Uploadify file upload plugin over other options that are availabe e.g. swfupload, fancyupload etc.

Answer (score 0):

Uploadify provides a very good jQuery wrapper around swfobject. If you're using jQuery and want to customise the look and feel of your uploads, its a great component to use.